# Raw resources aren't resolvable in android tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

`R.raw....` resources that are located in `src/androidTest/res/raw` can't be resolved in android tests after updating Android build tools to 4.7.3. Resources were resolvable before updating build tools.

`com.santaev.app.test.R` isn't resolved.

Build output:
`Unresolved reference: test`

Answer (score 0):

Android build tools 4.7.3 introduces `namespace` and `testNamespace` settings that allows to set package or generated file like `R`. Default values is same to package. `com.example.myapp.R` and `com.example.myapp.test.R` for tests).

See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#change-namespace-for-testing.

Looks like that after updating build tools property `testApplicationId` isn't more supported that leads manifest package to be used as namespace.

Removing `package` from manifest of android test sources and removing `testApplicationId`:

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    testApplicationId 'com.example.myapp.test.R' 
}
```

helped me.